# Search for .mp3 files in main folder and subfolders

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web, media

im looking to make a web player from scratch so I can control my music from my phone. I've got a listing of all files within a folder done, but I need to get it to list the files within the subfolders of the main folder.

So sort of something like \Path\ - Shows all in \Path\ and \Path\subs\ shows the contents of all subfolders.

This is the code that I have written to allow me to search a folder for .mp3 files, but I cannot pin the way to search in subfolders as well.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "music/",
    success: function(data){
        $(data).find("a:contains(.mp3)").each(function(){
            var files = $(this).text().replace(/  /g, '');
            files = $(this).text().replace(/.mp3/,'');
            $('<p></p>').html(files).appendTo('#displayer');
            $('#displayer > p:nth-child(odd)').css('background-color','#DDD');
        });
    }
});
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: In my opinion, searching in your server side with little code is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in `PHP`

```
<?php

// your mp3 dir
$dir = "dir/";
$result = array();

if(is_dir($dir)){
    $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $file){
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if("mp3"==$ext){
            $result[] = $file->getPathName();
        }
    }
    // you can echo json_encode(yourMp3Path) here.
    var_dump($result);
}
```